# Проверка наличия атрибута из массива

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть элемент, при клике на который происходит добавление данных в массив:

```
<a href="#" data-name="Apple" data-id="1" data-img="http://site.com/image.jpg" data-link="http://site.com/page">Item1</a>
<a href="#" data-name="IBM" data-id="2" data-img="http://site.com/image.jpg" data-link="http://site.com/page">Item2</a>
```

Это важные участки скрипта:

```
var myCart = (function () {

    var cart = [];

    function Item(name, id, img, link) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.img = img;
        this.link = link;
    }

    function saveCart() {
        localStorage.setItem("myCart", JSON.stringify(cart));
    }

    function loadCart() {
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myCart"));
        if (cart === null) {
            cart = [];
        }
    }

    loadCart();

    var obj = {};

    obj.addItemToCart = function (name, id, img, link) {
        for (var i in cart) {
            if (cart[i].name === name) {
                saveCart();
                return;
            }
        }

        var item = new Item(name, id, img, link);
        cart.push(item);
        saveCart();
    };

})();

$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
    var id = Number($(this).attr("data-id"));
    var img = $(this).attr("data-img");
    var link = $(this).attr("data-link");

});
```

Класс можно было добавить при нажатии на ссылку, но, после перезагрузки страницы он естественно исчезнет. Содержимое массива сохраняется в кеш. Как проверить содержимое массива по одному атрибуту, например, id и добавить класс к элементу, который содержит такой атрибут?

Comment: вы хотите элементам в доме класс добавить, или со строками в массиве это проделать?

Comment: Хочу, в кнопке добавляющей данные в массив оставлять класс, отображающий, что этот элемент уже добавлен в массив.

Comment: все равно не понял. но если есть id элемента в доме, то  `$('#'+id).addClass('new-class')`

Comment: Добавл код для понимания вопроса. Принцип прос, создали массив, при клике на ссылку, из нее собираем данные в атрибутах, закидываем в объект и сохраняем в массив. Затем массив сохраняем в кеш и запрашиваем при открытии страницы. Нужно пройтись по объектам в массиве и ссылкам на странице. При совпадении атрибутов добавить класс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var someId = ...;
var someClass = ...;
var arrayFromCache = ....;

if (arrayFromCache.find(function(item) { return item.id == someId; })) {
  $("a[data-id='" + someId + "']").addClass(someClass);
}
```

*Update*

```
(function () {

    var cart = [];

    function Item(name, id, img, link) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.img = img;
        this.link = link;
    }

    function saveCart() {
        localStorage.setItem("myCart", JSON.stringify(cart));
    }

    function loadCart() {
        var stored = localStorage.getItem("myCart");
        if (stored) {
          cart = JSON.parse(stored);
          for(var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
            $("a[data-id='" + cart[i].id + "']").addClass(someClass);
          }
        } else {
          cart = [];
        }
    }

    loadCart();

    function addItemToCart(name, id, img, link) {
        for (var i in cart) {
            if (cart[i].name === name) {
                return;
            }
        }

        var item = new Item(name, id, img, link);
        cart.push(item);
        saveCart();
    }

    $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
        var id = Number($(this).attr("data-id"));
        var img = $(this).attr("data-img");
        var link = $(this).attr("data-link");

        addItemToCart(name, id, img, link);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Добавил нужные участки скрипта, сможете немного скорректировать условие? На простом примере проверил, работает, а у себя применить не получается.

Comment: Спасибо, что внесли некоторые правки в код. Но, вопрос остался не решенным. Если бы кнопка была на странице одна, то есть, необходимо было сравнить наличие определенного значения в массиве и атрибута внутри одной ссылки, то ваш пример подошел (как и десятки других в сети). Но, ссылок будет много на странице. Я так понимаю, мне нужно собрать все атрибуты из ссылок на странице, а затем при совпадении значения добавить уже класс. С этим и возникает трудность.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev А-а-а, кажется, я понял. Сейчас.

Comment: Супер. Спасибо! Все оказалось намного проще, чем я городил изначально)